# Java algorithm go to list that contains lists of lists

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I want to get all elements from a list, but this element also has lists, until the list is null `(node.getChildNotes() == null)`.

I have tried the following, but its not an algorithm that works to endless deep.

```
private List<Layout> createChildList(Node node) {
        List<Layout> layouts = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            Node child = node.getChildNodes().item(count);
            if(child == null){
                break;
            }
            NodeList children = child.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                child = children.item(i);
                Layout layout = new Layout();
                layout.setName(child.getNodeName());
                layouts.add(layout);
            }
        count++
        }
        return layouts;
    }

private List<LayoutEntity> createChildList(Node node) {
        List<LayoutEntity> layouts = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node childNode = nodeList.item(i);
            LayoutEntity layout = new LayoutEntity();
            layout.setId(getIdByNode(childNode));
            layout.setName(childNode.getNodeName());
            layouts.add(layout);
            if (childNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                createChildList(childNode);
            }
        }
        return layouts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a deep recursive function you could first get all child Nodes of your parent Node and then simply create a `new Layout` for each Node afterwards.

```
private List<Node> createChildList(Node parent) {
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
        NodeList children = parent.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            result.addAll(createChildList(children.item(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the if condition, you get the child nodes and have a for loop in which you check all of this children. I don't know why would you need the while(true) loop. Just leave it like this.Also, the count variable is useless.

```
private List<Layout> createChildList(Node node) {
        List<Layout> layouts = new ArrayList<>();
        //int count = 0; WHY TO USE THIS USE THIS?
        Node child = node.getChildNodes().item(0);
        if(child == null){
            break;
        } else{
            NodeList children = child.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                child = children.item(i);
                Layout layout = new Layout();
                layout.setName(child.getNodeName());
                layouts.add(layout);
        }

        return layouts;
    }
```

Comment: but the children has also .getChildNotes()

Comment: So you would like to have every children in the same list, no matter if they are sons or grandsons, etc?

Comment: no i have to iterate every single children, thats inside of a children and a children...